# Regex Refinement

Tags: regex, search

I'm trying to parse addresses out of blocks of text, and have the following expression to do so:

```
/\d+\s(?:[sewnSEWN]\.?\s)?[\d\w]+\s(?:(?:[\d\w]+\s){0,3})?\w+\.?/
```

It will currently parse addresses such as:

300 E. Randolph St. Chicago, IL >> Returns 300 E. Randolph St.

5553 Bay Shore Drive >> Returns input

23 Joseph E Lowery Boulevard >> Returns input

513 Martin Luther King Jr Boulevard >> Returns input

This is exactly what I want. I was wondering, as this is the first expression I have ever written, if there was a way to shorten down the expression or refine it a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which implementation you are using, so translate this to relevant language when needed.

`\w = [a-zA-Z0-9]` so `[\d\w]` is same as `[\w]`

Note that `(?(?:[\w]+\s){0,3})?` is same as `(?:[\w]+\s){0,3}` because the expression inside is matched zero or more times.

You can also add in the `\w+\s` at the beginning to the above expression, and make it repeat from 1 to 4.

Here is a matching for your example, Knowing not much about your format, here is what I find odd.

```
/
  \d+                     # 513
  \s
  (?:[sewnSEWN]\.?\s)?    #
  (?:\w+\s){1,4}          # Martin Luther King Jr  
  \w+                     # Boulevard
  \.?
/
```

- The spaces are restricted to a single space `\s` is this that strict? Perhaps you want `\s+`
- If I understand you right, the portion after NSEW. directions are that there has to be atleast two words, and atmost 5 words separated by spaces. is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: I have it as single spaces because I assumed that's how standard addresses are broken up. The way I was trying to do it, the street name could contain at least one part (such as Randalph), and at most 4 different parts, and after the street name there would be the descripter, i.e. street, park, drive, etc. But they can be abbreviated, which is why I searched for the period after.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock makes sense. If you are trying to match generic street names, what about the directions like NW, SE etc?

Comment: I hadn't thought about that... Also, when I change `(?:(?:[\w]+\s){0,3})?` to `(?:[\w]+\s){0,3}?`, the second doesn't return the same result as the first.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock remove the `?` in your second expression.